# Expose alternate port for PCF Service

Tags: cloud-foundry, object-storage, pcfdev

I have an ECS bucket configured in my PCF ORG as a Content Storage service . The contents loaded there are exposed on port 9021 . The contents are accessed as links which directly hit the content as https://./bucketname/*.jpg or *.pdf . All works well on Desktop but when it comes to Mobile apps , seems 9021 is not an accepted port . Is there any way to expose the port for the service to 443 instead on 9021 without having to go through any external webserver . I tried to configure nginx_Buildpack and staticfile_buildpack to handle this , with no success there . Any help on this is highly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To encourage other users to help you with your issue, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please make use of the syntax highlighting feature.

Comment: Info about the service you're using would be helpful too. Name of the service provider/broker, type of service you're creating. If the service/broker is selecting the port 9021 then it's likely something you need to change on the service end, or you would need to run a proxy or gateway in front of your service, but then you're routing traffic through an extra layer so you have to consider if that is what you really want or if it's better to change the port on the service side and have clients connect directly to the service.